# Create a link to the current projects category page in Wordpress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, projects

I'm building a WP site using the 'Flexible Theme' form Elegant Themes. The site is currently viewable at www.hatchgallery.co.uk/hatchgallery.

When you click on one of the latest pieces of artwork on the home page (each one is a separate project) I want to be able to provide a link inside the info box. The link should go to the category page for that particular project. The general idea is that the category will be the artists name so clicking on this link will take you to all work by this artist.

I've started with this

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $project_category_link ); ?>">See More From This Artist</a>
```

But had no luck in getting it to work, any help?

Comment: Which link on the page is the one you are having problems with? What does `var_dump($project_category_link)` at that location provide?

Comment: It comes back 'NULL'. I do not have the link on the page, it would be above the 'contact us' and 'full information' links. Just want it to go to whatever category page is applied to that project...

Comment: Well then you should show the code where that value is defined, not where you are trying top output it, as that is where the problem lies.

Comment: My PHP skills are pretty non-existent unfortunately. Is there any other help you can give Mike?

Comment: Search through the codebase for other uses of `project_category_link` and see if your usage matches.  I really haven't touched Wordpress for years or have no specific experience with that theme, so someone more close to that sort of development may be able to give better advice on usage.

Comment: Ok, that's a good starting point, thank you Mike.